# Xcode and AdMob on iPhone 3.2

Tags: iphone, sdk, symbols, undefined, admob

How do I fix the following error:

Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AdMobView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-AdMobView in AdWhirlAdapterAdMob.o
ld: symbol(s) not found

Answer (score 1):

check your libraray search paths in your project info.  Make sure to remove the / slashes that sometimes appear outside of the quotes "" that contain your linked frameworks.

Also did you make sure to drag the Admob libraries into your project?